# DROP USER IF EXISTS syntax error in MySQL CLI

Tags: bash, mysql, database, sql

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Bash and MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper.

I try to create a DB stack for a webapp (WordPress) directly from command line and I share here the best way I know to do so and the problem I have with it (an answer might offer a better way).

I try to execute the following MySQL CLI code in which I use to create an authorized, all-privileged user + a DB instance with the same name:

```
cat <<-EOF | mysql -u root -p"$dbrootp_1"
    DROP USER IF EXISTS "$domain"@"localhost";
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "$domain";
    CREATE USER "$domain"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "$dbuserp_1";
    CREATE DATABASE "$domain";
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON "$domain".* TO "$domain"@"localhost";
EOF
```

Execution outputs the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>
> Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"example.com"' at line 1

I'm confused by this error: Is the problem in line 1 or line 2? What is the syntax error here? I must use variable expansion.

### Update according to answer

User **l0b0**, I tried working with `${x}` instead `"$x"` as you have shown but sadly it outputs the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-law.co.il@localhost' at line 1.

#### Output of cat without piping data to mysql:

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS example.com@localhost;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS example.com;
CREATE USER example.com@localhost IDENTIFIED BY MYPASSWORD;
CREATE DATABASE example.com;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON example.com.* TO example.com@localhost;
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: That is new enough for `DROP USER IF EXISTS`. What is the output of `printf "%q\n" "$domain"`?

Comment: The output for `printf "%q\n" "$domain"` is the domain: `exmaple.com`.

Comment: This is a useless use of cat. You can send stdin straight to mysql.

Comment: I assume you mean with a pipe @jordanm? Will you share example in a small answer?

Comment: It's not really an answer to your question, just pointing out that `cat` is redundant. To resolve your issues, I am pretty sure you need to change line 1 to: `DROP USER IF EXISTS \\`$domain\\`@\\`localhost\\`;`

Comment: The double quotes are not removed in the heredoc like they would be when providing a command with args. Double quotes are invalid for that, needs to be either backticks or single quotes.

Comment: Seems like I'll have to do this to the rest of the lines. This will create a unaesthetic, uncomfortable code to maintain. Is there really no better way to create a webapp dbstack in *nix systems or MySQL CLI?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jordanm points out, within [here documents](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) quotes are literal, not syntactical. So you want

```
mysql -u root -p"$dbrootp_1" <<-EOF
    DROP USER IF EXISTS ${domain}@localhost;
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${domain};
    CREATE USER ${domain}@localhost IDENTIFIED BY ${dbuserp_1};
    CREATE DATABASE ${domain};
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* TO ${domain}@localhost;
EOF
```

If you have special characters in your `$domain` or `$dbuserp_1` you'll need to quote them in [backticks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html):

```
mysql -u root -p"$dbrootp_1" <<-EOF
    DROP USER IF EXISTS \`${domain}\`@localhost;
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS \`${domain}\`;
    CREATE USER \`${domain}\`@localhost IDENTIFIED BY \`${dbuserp_1}\`;
    CREATE DATABASE `${domain}`;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`${domain}\`.* TO \`${domain}\`@localhost;
EOF
```

Comment: Sadly this outputs an error, pelase see update in question.

Comment: Try `cat`ting the command rather than passing it to `mysql` to see what the command actually ends up being.

Comment: Well the output in `cat` looks fine to me... I see the proper names in their places.

Comment: Please update your original question with the output of `cat`ting your command, so we can see what is being sent.

Comment: Just updated. Please see.

Comment: Is a domain hyphen (`-`) a "special character? I should write `first`-`example.com` this way? That's looks awful... :|

Comment: It's probably special, which is why I asked for the actual output, not trimmed or anonymized. I bare hyphen in SQL usually means "minus", after all.

Comment: Crap, my exact edit wasn't saved above. So everywhere I have to write: `firstBACKTICK-BACKTICKexample`.com?

Comment: You can't use backticks in an unquoted here-document without them being interpreted as a command substitution.